# Hypertext to a word in the entire text

Tags: hyperref, hyperlink

For my report, I use several terms that might not be clear for everybody. Therefore I made a terminology chapter where all these terms are explained. I would like to add a hyperlink reference to all words that are in the terminology chapter to this chapter. For example, the term "NDC" is used in the text. The user should be able to click on the word "NDC" and automatically go to the location where this word is explained in the terminology chapter.

I looked into the `hyperlink` package. With this package, this would be possible but I would have to add a reference for every word in the text. I was hoping for a package that will do this automatically for me. Does such a package exist?

Edit:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
        name=latex,
        description={Is a mark up language specially suited for 
scientific documents}
}

\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
        name=mathematics,
        description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}

\newglossaryentry{formula}
{
        name=formula,
        description={A mathematical expression}
}

\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}

\newacronym{lcm}{LCM}{Least Common Multiple}

\begin{document}

The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language is specially suitable 
for documents that include \gls{maths}. \Glspl{formula} are 
rendered properly an easily once one gets used to the commands.

Given a set of numbers, there are elementary methods to compute 
its \acrlong{gcd}, which is abbreviated \acrshort{gcd}. This 
process is similar to that used for the \acrfull{lcm}.



\clearpage

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\printglossary
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the glossaries package or acro. But you will nevertheless have to mark all NDC with e.g. \gls{NDC}.

Comment: `glossaries` does what you need.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thank you for your answer. This seems indeed in the right direction. However, it seems that the package does not automatically go to the glossary when you click on a word of the glossary. Even when you have mark them. Is that correct, or did I not implement the glossary correctly?

Comment: Sorry but how can I know if you implemented it correctly or not if you don't show your code. Add a minimal example. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, Very good point, I updated the question so that it includes my current implementation

Comment: Your example is incomplete, the class is missing. But beside this: you need to load hyperref if you want links.

Comment: Ah oke, thank you for your help

Comment: You could define macros like \def\NDC{\hyperlink{NDC}{NDC}\space} where the definition of NDC is given by \hypertarget{NDC}{NDC} ...